# How do I write all the lines into a csv file, not just the last line?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

How do I write the complete table into a new CSV file? I have looped through the necessary tuple, but I'm only getting the last line.

When I print out 'table' to the terminal, I get the whole rows and columns, but when I try to insert the rows/columns into the CSV file, it only shows the last line of the table. How do I change that?

The end goal is to merge it with another file and create a table with pandas.

This is one of the things I tried so far:

```
for row in zip(*([key] + (value) for key, value in sorted(dicti.items()))):
    table = [(*row,)]
    #print(table)
    with open('newfile.csv','w') as f:
        csv_f=csv.writer(f)
        csv_f.writerow(['first','middle', 'last'])
        for row in table:
            csv_f.writerow(row)
            csv_f.writerow('\n')
```

Thanks, your help will be appreciated. I can provide more information as needed.

Comment: The example input data you provided doesn't match the example output - you have 3 lists of different lengths with no way to correlation between the 3, yet you know that one of the people has no middle name.

Comment: Thanks for your input, it helped me improve the code to accommodate the names that equal 'NULL'

Answer (score 0):

In the standard library there is a function that take n lists and generates tuples with elements of each lists:

https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#zip